# Adding page to multipage

Tags: vba, excel

I use Excel 2016

I want to add a page to a Multi Page control.
For some reason I get the error "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch"

I have a blank Excel file with a UserForm. On the UserForm I have a CommandButton and a MultiPage, both are out of the box. I added the following code to the CommandButton

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim myPage As Page
    Set myPage = Me.MultiPage1.Pages.Add("testpage", "TestPage")
End Sub
```

Do I need to add references to some toolkit for this to work? For the moment I have the following references active

- Visual Basic For Applications
- Microsfot Excel 16.0 Object Library
- OLE Automation
- Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library
- Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library

When I write the Dim myPage declaration I get a list of objects.. I have two Page objects? Also when I write

```
myPage.
```

to get a list of available things for that object I see the following

- CenterFooter
- CenterHeader
- LeftFooter
- LeftHeader
- RightFooter
- RightHeader

So I assume myPage object is not from the right Page type

Comment: Declare it as `MSForms.Page`

Answer (score 1):

This works also:

`MultiPage1.Pages.Add "tst1", "TestPage"`

Answer (score 0):

This works without getting a reference to the new Page object

```
Me.MultiPage1.Pages.Add
Me.MultiPage1.Pages(Me.MultiPage1.Pages.Count - 1).Name = "testpage"
Me.MultiPage1.Pages(Me.MultiPage1.Pages.Count - 1).Caption = "TestPage"
Debug.Print Me.MultiPage1.Pages(Me.MultiPage1.Pages.Count - 1).Name
Debug.Print Me.MultiPage1.Pages(Me.MultiPage1.Pages.Count - 1).Caption
```

Comment: It will be a better answer if you include the need to clarify the msforms library per the other comments

Answer (score -4):

The easy non code way:
Left click->New Page